# Missing documents for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I submitted my application at the TLS London centre on friday. It was checked by the TLS contact and was sent off. However today I received an email from TLS saying that my application could not be processed by the French Consulate because I did not include a French visa application form. I’m very confused as I obviously included the form, and all my documents were checked at the TLS centre?! On the portal however it says my application has been processed and sent back to the TLS centre. What do I do as I am pretty certain I included the form. Unless they’re referring to a form other than the Schengen visa application form?

Comment: Go there to confirm the exact form that was omitted. Until then, don't panic.

Comment: I am having the same issue - did you find out what the 'missing French Visa application form' is?